# Why is ZeroMQ PUB enqueing messages with no connected subscribers? ( Well, "disconnected" SUB-s )

Tags: zeromq

I am seeing a strange behavior using **`ZMQ_PUB`**.

I have a producer which `.connect()`-s to different processes
that `.bind()` on `ZMQ_SUB` sockets.

The subscribers all `.bind()`, the publisher `.connect()`-s.

When a producer starts, it creates a `ZMQ_PUB` socket and `.connect()`-s it to different processes. It then immediately starts sending messages at a regular period.

As expected, if there are no connected subscribers, it drops all messages, until a subscriber starts.

The flow works normal then, when a subscriber starts, it receives the messages from that moment on.

**Now, the problem is:**

1. I disconnect the subscriber ( stopping the process ).
2. There are no active subscribers at this point, as I stopped the only one. The producer continues sending messages, which should be dropped, as there are no connected subscribers anymore…
3. I restart the original subscriber, it binds, the publisher reconnects... and the subscriber receives all messages produced in the meantime !!

So what I see is that the producer enqueued all messages while the subscriber was down. As soon as the socket reconnected, because the subscriber process restarted, it sent all queued messages.

As I understood from [**here**](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html), a publisher should drop all sent messages when there are no connected subscribers:

> [ZeroMQ examples](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html)
>   "A publisher has no connected subscribers, then it will simply drop all messages."

**Why is this happening?**

By the way, I am using C++ over linux for these tests.

I tried setting a different identity on the subscriber when it binds, but it didn't work. Publisher still enqueues messages, and delivers them all when subscriber restart.

Thanks in advance,

Luis

---

**UPDATE:**

> IMPORTANT UPDATE!!!!!
> Before posting this question
> I had tried different solutions. One was to set **`ZMQ_LINGER`** to 0, which didn't work.
> I added **`ZMQ:IMMEDIATE`**, and it worked, but I just found out that `ZMQ:IMMEDIATE` alone does not work. It requires also **`ZMQ_LINGER`**.
> [Luis Rojas 3 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700291/why-is-zeromq-pub-enqueing-messages-with-no-connected-subscribers-well-lost/41715485?noredirect=1#comment70648617_41700876)

**UPDATE:**
As per request, I am adding some simple test cases to show my point. 
One is a simple subscriber, which runs on command line and receives the uri where to bind, for instance :

$ ./sub tcp://127.0.0.1:50001

The other is a publisher, which receives a list of uris to connect to, for instance :

./pub tcp://127.0.0.1:50001 tcp://127.0.0.1:50002

The subscriber receives up to 5 messages, then closes socket and exit. We can see on wireshark the exchange of FIN/ACK, both ways, and how the socket moves to TIME_WAIT state. Then, publisher starts sending SYN, trying to reconnect (that probes the ZMQ_PUB knows that connection closed)

I am explicitely not unsubscribing the socket, just closing it. In my opinion, if the socket closed, the publisher should automatically end any subscription for that connection.

So what I see is : I start subscriber(one or more), I start publisher, which starts sending messages. Subscriber receives 5 messages and ends. In the meantime publisher continues sending messages, WITH NO CONNECTED SUBSCRIBER. I restart the subscriber, and receives immediately several messages, because they were queued at the publishers side. I think those queued messages break the Publish/Subscribe model, where messages should be delivered only to connected subscribers. If a susbcriber closes the connection, messages to that subscriber should be dropped. Even more, when subscriber restarts, it may decide to subscribe to other messages, but it will still receive those subscribed by a "previous encarnation" that was binded at same port.

My proposal is that ZMQ_PUB (on connect mode), when detecting a socket disconnection, should clear all subscriptions on that socket, until it reconnects and the NEW subscriber decides to resubscribe.

I apologize for language mistakes, but english is not my native language.

Pub's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string>
#include <zeromq/zmq.hpp>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage : %s <remoteUri1> [remoteUri2...]\n",   
        basename( argv[0] ) );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    std::string pLocalUri( argv[1] );
    zmq::context_t localContext( 1 );
    zmq::socket_t *pSocket = new zmq::socket_t( localContext, ZMQ_PUB );
    if ( NULL == pSocket )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't create socket. Aborting...\n" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int i;
    try
    {
        for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
        {
            printf( "Connecting to [%s]\n", argv[i] );
            {
                pSocket->connect( argv[i] );
            }
        }
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't connect socket to %s. Aborting...\n", argv[i] );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf( "Publisher Up and running... sending messages\n" );
    fflush(NULL);

    int msgCounter = 0;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            char msgBuffer[1024];
            sprintf( msgBuffer, "Message #%d", msgCounter++ );
            zmq::message_t outTask( msgBuffer, strlen( msgBuffer ) + 1 );
            printf("Sending message [%s]\n", msgBuffer );
            pSocket->send ( outTask );
            sleep( 1 );
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Some unknown error ocurred. Aborting...\n" );
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    while ( true );

    exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Sub's code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string>
#include <zeromq/zmq.hpp>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage : %s <localUri>\n", basename( argv[0] ) );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    std::string pLocalUri( argv[1] );
    zmq::context_t localContext( 1 );
    zmq::socket_t *pSocket = new zmq::socket_t( localContext, ZMQ_SUB );
    if ( NULL == pSocket )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't create socket. Aborting...\n" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    try
    {
        pSocket->setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0 );
        pSocket->bind( pLocalUri.c_str() );
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't bind socket. Aborting...\n" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int msgCounter = 0;
    printf( "Subscriber Up and running... waiting for messages\n" );
    fflush( NULL );

    do
    {
        try
        {
            zmq::message_t inTask;
            pSocket->recv ( &inTask );
            printf( "Message received : [%s]\n", inTask.data() );
            fflush( NULL );
            msgCounter++;
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Some unknown error ocurred. Aborting...\n" );
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    while ( msgCounter < 5 );

    // pSocket->setsockopt( ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE, "", 0 ); NOT UNSUBSCRIBING
    pSocket->close();
    exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: Hope, Luis, you do not mind a few light polishing touches on the post. Also feel free to enjoy some other pieces of experience collected in the ZeroMQ posts **in >>> http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a3666197%20%5bzeromq%5d Anyway, enjoy the smart landscapes of ZeroMQ support for distributed systems' designs!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Q: Why is this happening?

Because the `SUB` is actually still connected ( not "disconnected" enough ).

Yes, might be surprising, but **killing** the **`SUB`**-process, be it on `.bind()`- or `.connect()`-attached side of the socket's transport-media, **does not mean**, the Finite-State-Machine of the I/O-pump has "moved" into disconnected-state.

Given that, the **`PUB`**-side has no other option but to consider the **`SUB`**-side still live and connected ( even while the process was silently killed beyond the line-of-sight of the `PUB`-side ) and for such "distributed"-state there is a ZeroMQ protocol-defined behaviour ( a `PUB`-side duty ) to collect all the interim messages for a ( yes, invisibly dead ) `SUB`-scriber, which the `PUB`-side still considers fair to live ( but might be having just some temporally intermitent issues somewhere low, on the transport I/O-levels or some kinds of remote CPU-resources starvations or concurrency-introduced transiently intermitent { local | remote } blocking states et al ).

### So it buffers...

In case your assassination of the **`SUB`**-side agent would appear to have been a bit more graceful ( using the zeroised `ZMQ_LINGER` + an adequate `.close()` on the socket-resource instance ) the **`PUB`**-side will recognise the "distributed"-system system-wide Finite-State-Automaton shift into an indeed "DISCONNECT"-ed state and a due change-of-behaviour will happen on the `PUB`-side of the "distributed-FSA", not storing any messages for this "visibly" indeed "DISCONNECT"-ed **`SUB`** -- exactly what the documentation states.

"Distributed-FSA" has but quite a weak means to recognise state-change events "beyond it's horizon of *localhost* contols. **`KILL`**-ing a remote process, which implements some remarkable part of the "distributed-FSA" is a devastating event, not a method how to keep the system work. A good option for such external risks might be

---

### Sounds complex?

Oh, yes, it is complex, indeed. That's exactly why ZeroMQ solved this for us, to be free and enjoy designing our application architectures based on top of these ( already solved ) low level complexities.

---

### Distributed-system FSA ( a system-wide FSA of layered composition of sub-FSA-s )

To just imagine what is silently going on under the hood, imagine just having a simple, tandem pair of FSA-FSA - exactly what the pair of **`.Context()`** instances try to handle for us in the simplest ever 1:1 **`PUB/SUB`** scenario where the use-case `KILL`-s all the sub-FSA-s on the `SUB`-side without giving a shot to acknowledge the intention to the `PUB`-side. Even the TCP-protocol ( living both on the `PUB`-side and `SUB`-side ) has several state-transition from [**`ESTABLISHED`**] to [**`CLOSED`**] state.

---

### A quick X-ray view on a distributed-systems' FSA-of-FSA-s

( just the TCP-protocol FSA was depicted for clarity )

**`PUB`**-side:

[image]

---

`.socket( .. )` instance's behaviour FSA:

[image]

---

**`SUB`**-side:

[image]

(Courtesy nanomsg).

Comment: I completely disagree. The SUB side was not simply "silently killed beyond the line-of-sight". It correctly closed the socket. I can send you the wireshark traces, if you don't believe me. The TCP socket was closed, I can see the FIN/ACK messages and how the socket on the SUB side went to TIME_WAIT. Even more, I can see the PUB side starts to send SYN messages, trying to reconnect. So, the ZMQ_PUB socket knows the connection closed, From that moment it should know there is no SUB connected anymore and should start dropping messages! It clearly seems like a bug in ZeroMQ to me.

Comment: Welcome, Luis. Given the new information posted in the comment above, would you mind to document the fully compatible MCVE ( the **M**-inimum **C**-omplete **V**-erifiable **E**-xample ) of the experiment to be able to re-run and potentially reproduce 1:1 the claimed observation? That would be the fastest path to the Occam Razor.

Answer (score 4):

Bind and Connect although indifferent, have specific meaning here.

**Option 1:**

Change your code to this way and there's no problem:

1. Publisher should `bind` to an address
2. Subscriber should `connect` to that address

'coz if you bind a subscriber and then interrupt it, there's no way the publisher knows that the subscriber is unbound and so it queues the messages to the bound port and when you restart again on the same port, the queued messages will be drained.

**Option 2:**

But if you want to do it your way, you need to do the following things:

1. Register an interrupt handler (`SIGINT`) in the subscriber code
2. On the interrupt of the subscriber do the following:

   - `unsubscribe` the topic
   - `close` the sub socket
   - exit the subscriber process cleanly with preferably 0 return code

**UPDATE:**

Regarding the point of identity, do not assume that setting identity will uniquely identify a connection. If it is left to zeromq, it will assign the identities of the incoming connections using unique arbitrary numbers.

Identities are not used to respond back to the clients in general. They are used for responding back to the clients in case `ROUTER` sockets are used. 
'Coz ROUTERsockets are asynchronous where as REQ/REP are synchronous. In Async we need to know to whom we respond back. It can be n/w address or a random number or uuid etc.

**UPDATE:**

I don't consider this as in issue with zeromq because  throughout the guide PUB/SUB is explained in the way that Publisher is generally static (Server and is bound to a port) and subscribers come and go along the way (Clients which connect to the port).

There is another option which would exactly fit to your requirement
`ZMQ_IMMEDIATE` or `ZMQ_DELAY_ATTACH_ON_CONNECT`

Setting the above socket option on the publisher would not let the messages en queue when there are no active connections to it.

Comment: Option 1 shoudl not be needed. ZeroMQ documentation is very clear, that it doesn't matter which parts binds or connects, the important part is the ZMQ_TYPE. Per design for my problem, subscribers must bind.
Option2 : It has no sense. What do you mean the publisher has no way to know there is no subscriber anymore? it must know, as the TCP socket was disconnected. There maybe many reasons why the subscriber disappeared, including hardware crash. The ZMQ_PUB socket must not depend on the behavior of subscriber.
If there are no connected subscribers, publisher should drop messages.

Comment: True. But that is true mostly for 1-1 communication. It only means either party can start communication without waiting for the other party. But remember `bind` will perform a socket bind to the port given and `connect` will perform a bind to another arbitrary port waiting on connection with the supplied port. There's a lot of difference between them

Comment: @LuisRojas Please read this from zmq documentation and you get the difference

"Although ZeroMQ tries to be neutral about which side binds and which side connects, there are differences. We'll see these in more detail later. The upshot is that you should usually think in terms of "servers" as static parts of your topology that bind to more or less fixed endpoints, and "clients" as dynamic parts that come and go and connect to these endpoints. "

Comment: @LuisRojas Also read this point from "Plugging sockets into Topology" section

Your application code cannot work with these connections directly; they are encapsulated under the socket.

Comment: Yes, and my subscribers are statics, while the publisher is a temporary one that comes and goes.

Comment: The application doesn't need to deal with the connection directly. The publisher really shouldn't care if there is an encapsulated connected socket or not. The publisher just "sends messages". Now, when the subscriber ends not only unbinds a socket, it also closes the connected one. The encapsulated socket at the publisher side must notice that. In fact, it does, because it tries to reconnect to the remote side. The concept in the Publish/Subscribe model is that messages are sent only to connected subscribers. PUB/SUB messages must never be enqueued.

Comment: To me this sounds like a bug in the ZeroMQ library. PUB/SUB messages should never be enqueued. If there is no connected socket they should be dropped, always. ZeroMQ, at the lower layer, knows when there is really a connected socket or not.

Comment: I've **UPDATED** another option which would fit your needs. Check and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the ZMQ_IMMEDIATE option worked perfect. 
In most forums it is said that it doesn't matter which side binds, for instance :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752338/zeromq-which-socket-should-bind-on-pubsub-pattern/41705865#41705865
You can see there that I added a description of what I am doing with this model:
Basically, I am broadcasting commands from some "administrator console" to a group of processes. This console can run from anywhere, and so the processes cam't connect(), because they don't know where to. They just expect commands. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Pls upvote my answer since it worked. If i get 50 reputation, i'll be able to comment on others posts.

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE!!!!!
Before posting this question I had tried different solutions. One was to set ZMQ_LINGER to 0, which didn't work.  I added ZMQ:IMMEDIATE, and it worked, but I just found out that ZMQ:IMMEDIATE alone does not work. It requires also ZMQ_LINGER.